# validate and show the error in ag grid cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag grid community edition with angular for my table.

I like to make a editable table with validation.

If validation fails I need to show the error with red border in ag gird cell as like below image

My Validation :

When User clicks the save button.

The user should enter the both last name & qualification.

If user enters either any one of this, then I need to show the red border on the cell

If the user didn't entered both, then it can pass

Please help me achieve this. I tried with cellstyle, But it is not fitting for my case

Below is my Stackblitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fq2wvt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

Comment: Hello Rajesh, I am not familiar with ag-grid but found one article, where the author explains how to use FormArray with ag-grid. For me, it was difficult to understand, but maybe it can help you. https://blog.ag-grid.com/using-angular-forms-with-ag-grid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to use `cellClassRules` with one global flag for signalling save attempt.

Setup this simple object as class member:

```
  cellRules = {
    'rag-red': params => this.isSaveAttempted && !params.value
  };
```

initialize "save attempt":

```
isSaveAttempted = false;
```

then assign to column defs (last name, qualification):

```
{
  headerName: 'Last Name',
  field: 'lastName',
  editable: true,
  cellClassRules: this.cellRules // <-- here
},
{ headerName: 'Address', field: 'address', editable: true },
{
  headerName: 'Qualification',
  field: 'qualification',
  editable: true,
  cellClassRules: this.cellRules // <-- here
}
```

css rule in component (to make it work `ng-deep` is needed), but you can also add to `styles.css` and then no `ng-deep`.

```
:host::ng-deep .rag-red {
  border: 3px solid red !important;
}
```

once user clicks on 'Save` button:

```
  onSave(): void {
    this.isSaveAttempted = true;
    this.gridApi.redrawRows(); <-- this will trigger redraw and red borders
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbmw9a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thanks for your help Robert. But your solution is validating entire grid. 
Even un edited rows also showing in red color. I want to show the error only which is edited by the user

Comment: @RajeshKumar  Check this new [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kcjsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)